# Google Drive API Transfer ownership

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

Background:

Language: Python
Libs version:
oauth2client (1.4.6)
apiclient (1.0.2)

Script tasks:

1 - Search for files shared with account "A" by account "B"

```
param['pageToken'] = page_token
param['maxResults'] = 1000
param['q'] = "not '%s' in owners and trashed = false" % (account_A_email)
files = service.files().list(**param).execute()
```

2 - Impersonate as account "B" using "SignedJwtAssertionCredentials" and set account "A" as owner

```
new_permission = {}
new_permission['value'] = account_A_email
new_permission['type'] = 'user'
new_permission['role'] = 'owner'
service.permissions().insert(fileId=file_id, body=new_permission).execute()
# Note: I have tried service.permissions().update() but it did not work
```

Issue:

Once the new permission applied on any file, the file appears on account "A" root folder as well as the original location. This behavior is similar to "Add to my Drive" in the Drive UI.

Any idea how to stop the "Add to my Drive" behavior?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: post the code if you want help

Comment: I have added the Google API related functions

Comment: seems the other one remains as writer and you might need to remove him after ownership change

Comment: That is actually correct behavior

Comment: yes its correct behavior and is what you need to prevent to achieve what you need, by making an extra api call.

Comment: I just tried that, even after removing the writer role, the file still appear under "My Drive" for account A.

Comment: hmm and shows as reader or no access?

Answer (score 4):

Ok I did the following and it worked after couple of hours and loads of cups of coffee :)

Instead of using "which causes the issue":

```
service.permissions().insert(fileId=file_id, body=new_permission).execute()
```

Use the following:

```
param_perm['value'] = new_owner
param_perm['type'] = 'user'
param_perm['role'] = 'owner'
service.permissions().update(fileId=file_id,
                             permissionId=perm_id,
                             body=param_perm,
                             transferOwnership=True).execute()
```

What changed from my previous trial is the permissionId which is the "new owner" permission id **not** the previous owner.

Comment: how do you set perm_id?

Comment: yes @somer-rajab , can you share the code you used to set perm_id value? Does this work with Drive API v3 version? Thanks

Comment: @abu you can get the permission id by service.permissions().list(fileId=fileId).execute(http=http)